# Anaconda prompt has disappeared after running conda update

Tags: python, anaconda, prompt

I had a conda environment in my PC and yesterday I updated dependencies in that env using the command `conda update --env`. But when I tried to find Anaconda Prompt in the windows search bar today, that is not showing. I search all the questions regarding this problem on the SO, but many answers were not helpful or with broken links. I'm somewhat new to conda, therefore any helpful suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does `conda info --envs` give something still?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle between the conda environment as such:

```
$ conda activate # this will enter the conda shell
$ conda deactivate # this will leave the conda shell
```

Let me know if you need any more help.